# Restore TFS Website in IIS Manager

Tags: iis, team-foundation-server

I've accidently deleted the Tfs site in IIS Manager. I've tried reinstalling TFS but it didn't come back. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall, install, then run the add an AT wizard to restore TFS. Point the wizard to the SQL Server that hosts the data from the original instance.

Here is the MSDN topic for using the add an AT wizard for disaster recovery.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259689.aspx

Comment: umm... what's AT?

Comment: Sorry, AT is application tier, essentially all the guts of TFS (IIS sites, windows services, etc) except for the data. Read the section in the linked topic on disaster recovery. Good luck!